# How to run jQuery Method from String

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Let's say we have the following jQuery plugins

```
$.accordion();
$.button();
```

and in a script we have the following code:

```
var plg = "accordion";

$('selector').plg();

plg = 'button';

$('selector').plg();
```

The above example, ofcource doesn't work. But is there a way to do something similar, without the usage of eval() ?

Can I execute jQuery plugins from variable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can!

```
var plg = "accordion";

$('selector')[plg]();
```

Comment: That was the correct answer :) It works fine ! I will check it as correct in 3 minutes :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to make an alias for that function you can just assign it, no need for a string or `eval`:

```
var plg = $.accordion;

$('selector').plg();
```

Comment: This is not wat I need. I want to run my plugin from a variable name. In example var plg = "pluginname"; $('selector').plg(); Is it posible to make the same thing like var plg = $."pluginname"; ?

Comment: Mmmm, it wasn't very clear by your question, but roXon's answer seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response anyway :)